# Vim: Open each buffer in a new tab

Tags: vim

I am wondering how I can open all of the current buffers in vi(m) in new tabs.
I know that you can edit your vimrc file to do something like this, but I'd prefer just to be able to run a command when needed.
I can do it manually by chaining the new tab and open buffer commands, such as:

```
:tabnew | b 1
```

But I would prefer a more automatic approach.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

you can assign a mapping to this command:

```
:bufdo tab split
```

- explanation:

  - **bufdo [command]** apply the [command] to all buffers
  - **tab split** take the current buffer and open a tab with it

finally, to map this:

```
map ,bt :bufdo tab split<CR>
```

greets

Answer (score 63):

The way to go is:

```
:tab sball
```

From the help:

"sball: Rearrange the screen to open one window for each buffer in the buffer list... When the |:tab| modifier is used new windows are opened in a new tab, up to 'tabpagemax'."

Without the |:tab| modifier, it open each buffer in split view.

```
:sball
```

or to open at most 6 of them

```
:6sball
```

etc.

Comment: Don't forget the vaguely sports-sounding "vertical ball" to split about the y-axis.

Comment: For some reason `:tab sball` is also splitting my current tab into 5 different horizontal splits.  Odd...

Comment: @sixtyfootersdude You probably have some kind of plugin interfering (or you already have the windows split before the `:tab` command (this could happen in a script/from the command line)

Answer (score 10):

[I would have commented on the accepted answer above but haven't enough rep points.]

For me the accepted answer leaves the new tabs without syntax highlighting, if they are buffers that have never been previously viewed.  (To reproduce - select a number of XML files, choose Edit with Single Vim in Windows Explorer, try it from there.)  I don't know why this happens so my solution is just to turn syntax highlighting on again.

I also find it annoying that the last buffer ends up with two tabs, so my solution is to move to the last tab and close it.

```
:bufdo tab split
:tablast
:tabclose
:syntax on
```

So in a mapping,

```
:map ,bt :bufdo tab split<CR>:tablast<CR>:tabclose<CR>:syntax on<CR>
```